# how to implement two different animations on same sprite in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I'm confused on using animations in cocos2d... I've a sprite which has 3 types of animations, like a smiley which laughs, cries and winks eyes... And I have separate sprite sheets for each of these animations... how will I be able to use these animations on the same sprite... Can anybody help me please???

Regards,

Suraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much easier to have all your animations on the same sprite sheet, as, if your sprite is using a CCBatchnode to do it's draw method, you'd have remove it as a child from 1 sheet, and readd it to another.

In your CCSprite subclass, set some CCAction's as instance variables.

In an initialization method, write those actions and store them to the instance variables.

Then when you want to use an animation, tell your sprite to run it.

E.g.

```
NSMutableArray *smileFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
[smileFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"character_smile.png"]];
[smileFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"character_smile2.png"]];
[smileFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"character_smile3.png"]];


CCAnimation *smileAnim = [CCAnimation 
                         animationWithFrames:smileFrames delay:0.2f];

self.smileAction = [CCSequence actions:
                   [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:smileAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO],
                   [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(smileFinished)],
                   nil];
```

Then you would simply use..

```
[sprite runAction:smileAction];
```

I have added a CCCallFunc to the end of the animation, as you may want to revert back to an idle animation after it is finished.

Don't forget to release any retained actions when the sprite is deallocated.

Comment: thanks for the help... But, what i need is to place animations in different sprite sheets and use them...

Comment: how big are your spritesheets and animations???, they must be huge. As far as i know, cocos2d does not support animations that cross over onto different spritesheets, mainly for the reason that the batchnode object is responsible for the draw method of every sprite that is attached to it. Like i said, you could work out a way of removing the sprite from its parent spritesheet, and readding it to the spritesheet you need, but in my opinion you need to optimise your sheets.

Comment: I solved the problem by resizing the texture.... Thanks for your help dude... But, still I've a confusion... Isn't it possible to load two spritesheets at the same time? I mean, for different sprites...

Comment: Yes, ofcourse you can. However, for the spritesheet to handle the sprite's draw method (much better fps with multiple sprites), the sprites must be a child of that spritesheet. If often use an enemy spritesheet, and a player+hud spritesheet. I have both of these batchnodes as children to my GameLayer.